# Cannot complete steps in Gmail's 'Add another email address you own' feature

Tags: gmail

Clicking **Gmail** -> **Settings** -> **Accounts and Import** -> **Add another email address you own** option pops up the following dialog box:

[image]

No matter the options I select or domain I use, I cannot get past this page. Clicking on "Next Step" does nothing.

This is in vanilla Internet Explorer 11 on Windows 7 64.

Comment: what do you mean you cannot get past the page?

Comment: Um, how about: clicking **Next Step** does nothing.

Comment: Try on a different browser. Ensure you're using a valid email address.

Comment: I smell a hidden JavaScript error. Everything else could give you at least an error message. Try a different browser as @AlE. said. Chrome should be fine.

Comment: @ytg Submit that as an answer and I will mark it resolved. It is surprising to me how Google is deciding to shun so many users across so many platforms.

Comment: It's not that Google shuns people. Programming errors happen. And they can't test everything on every browser, especially if those browsers are not their highest priority. I know that mine isn't ;)

Comment: @ytg Just out of curiosity, is your user-base billions of users? (o;

Comment: No, my user base is big corporations who care enough that the one browser installed on their intranet (yes, it's IE) is supported to put it in the contract. So yes, I _need_ to support it, and I only need to support that, yet it's not my highest priority ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's most likely a JavaScript error. Everything else should give a proper error message, while JavaScript errors tend to just silently fail in the background, noticeable only in the developer consoles of the browsers.

Using an other browser than Internet Explorer should solve the problem: for example Chrome, Firefox or maybe even Edge should be fine.